# Java Object Instance creation problems

Tags: java, bluej

So I've been struggling all day today trying to create an instance of a class called 'Sport'.
I've got my code set up so I run the User Interface, which then runs a constructor, which then runs another constructor which loads the Sport values from a text file.

The problem is, the way I'm apparently creating the objects is wrong. Could really use some help.

```
public static void seperateValues(String sportDetail)
{

    String[] sportDetails = sportDetail.split(",");
    System.out.println("Adding new sport to the Sport collection");
    System.out.println(sportDetail);

    /*
    for(int i=0; i<sportDetails.length; i++) //just used for testing whether it was splitting correctly
    {
       System.out.println(sportDetails[i]); 
    }  */ 

    // name,usagefee,insurance,affiliationfees, then court numbers
    //Tennis,44,10,93,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
    int vlength;
    vlength = sportDetail.length();

    String[] sportDetailz;
    sportDetailz = new String[vlength];    
    sportDetailz[0] = sportDetails[0]; //name
    sportDetailz[1] = sportDetails[1]; //usage fees
    sportDetailz[2] = sportDetails[2]; //insurance
    sportDetailz[3] = sportDetails[3]; //afflcationfees

    String vSportObjectName;
    vSportObjectName = sportDetails[0];

    String sportinstance;
    sportinstance = sportDetails[0]; //this is the name of the sport which I'm hoping each loop around 
    //it will give a new name to
    Sport sportinstance = new Sport(sportDetails); 
   //System.out.println(Sport.this.name);

}
```

Error message: `variable sportinstance is already defined in method seperateValues(java.lang.String)`

http://puu.sh/2zil9

Comment: Please provide the error message as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: You're re-using a variable name; don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue is that you first declare `sportinstance` as a `String`. You then try to define it again as a `Sport`.

Just remove the following lines and try again (as it doesn't look like they actually are used anywhere else):

```
String sportinstance;
sportinstance = sportDetails[0];
```

The other option would be to simply rename either one of your instances of `sportinstance`.

Comment: I'm trying to make my program work so that each time the method loops, it creates the object instance with a new name. So 'sportinstance' each time around is a new sport.

either being 'tennis' or 'soccer'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to define `sportinstance` as two different datatypes and Java will not allow this. Either change the name of the `Sport` definition of `sportinstance` to another variable name or remove the definition.